# Targeting the correct HTML with htmlunit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

**Overview**

I am working on a project to web scrape a local theater's site for films that are now playing. My goal is to eventually embed this information (film title, film description, etc.) into an email via JSON that is sent every morning letting us know what is playing without actually having to visit their site or download their application.

Base URL for this project: https://www.landmarktheatres.com/albany-ny/spectrum-8-theatres

**Problem**

Using `htmlunit` I have been successful in extracting the film titles from the [base url](https://www.landmarktheatres.com/albany-ny/spectrum-8-theatres). However, included in these titles are the upcoming films which are also provided in the [base url](https://www.landmarktheatres.com/albany-ny/spectrum-8-theatres) `HTML`.

I need help in targeting the correct `HTML`. My current code utilizes an `HtmlElement` list:

```
 List<HtmlElement> itemList = page.getByXPath("//li[@class='gridCol-s-12 gridCol-m-4 gridCol-l-4']");
```

Then I am looping through that list to pull out the titles:

```
String title = ((HtmlElement) htmlItem.getFirstByXPath(".//div[@class='filmItemCopy']")).asText();
String titleOnly = title.substring(0, title.indexOf("\n"));
```

I have been inspecting the `HTML` and know that I need to target:

```
<section class="gridRow section content">
<div class="navTabs">
<div class="navTabItem active" data-tab-item="#showing">
```

To accomplish this, I am pretty sure I need to change my `List<HTMLElement>` to reflect this, but I am just not getting it to work. I tried the following to no avail:

```
 List<HtmlElement> itemList = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='navTabItem active']");
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"title":"FOUR GOOD DAYS"}
{"title":"LIMBO"}
{"title":"DEMON SLAYER THE MOVIE: MUGEN TRAIN (SUBTITLED)"}
{"title":"DEMON SLAYER THE MOVIE: MUGEN TRAIN (DUBBED)"}
{"title":"STREET GANG: HOW WE GOT TO SESAME STREET"}
{"title":"TOGETHER TOGETHER"}
{"title":"NOMADLAND"}
{"title":"THE TRUFFLE HUNTERS"}
{"title":"THE FATHER"}
```

**Current Output**

```
{"title":"FOUR GOOD DAYS"}
{"title":"LIMBO"}
{"title":"DEMON SLAYER THE MOVIE: MUGEN TRAIN (SUBTITLED)"}
{"title":"DEMON SLAYER THE MOVIE: MUGEN TRAIN (DUBBED)"}
{"title":"STREET GANG: HOW WE GOT TO SESAME STREET"}
{"title":"TOGETHER TOGETHER"}
{"title":"NOMADLAND"}
{"title":"THE TRUFFLE HUNTERS"}
{"title":"THE FATHER"}
{"title":"DREAM HORSE"}
{"title":"FINAL ACCOUNT"}
{"title":"FINDING YOU"}
{"title":"THE DRY"}
{"title":"THE HUMAN FACTOR"}
{"title":"WRATH OF MAN"}
```

**CODE**

**SpectrumFilmItems.java**

```
package org.example;

public class SpectrumFilmItems {
    private String title;


    public SpectrumFilmItems(String title) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**SpectrumScraper.java**

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SilentCssErrorHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class SpectrumScraper
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // GET request to obtain HTML content from the web server.
        String baseUrl = "https://www.landmarktheatres.com/albany-ny/spectrum-8-theatres";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        try {
            HtmlPage page = client.getPage(baseUrl);

            List<HtmlElement> itemList = page.getByXPath("//li[@class='gridCol-s-12 gridCol-m-4 gridCol-l-4']");

            if(itemList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("No item found.");
            }else {
                for (HtmlElement htmlItem : itemList) {
                    String title = ((HtmlElement) htmlItem.getFirstByXPath(".//div[@class='filmItemCopy']")).asText();
                    String titleOnly = title.substring(0, title.indexOf("\n"));


                    SpectrumFilmItems filmItem = new SpectrumFilmItems(titleOnly);

                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(filmItem);
                    System.out.println(jsonString);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consistent difference between existing and non-released films is the attribute `data-film-session` and `data-film-exp`. Only add to the list if the entry has one or both of these attributes. This is untested, it may not work, but it's a step in the right direction.

```java
for (HtmlElement htmlItem : itemList) {
    String dataFilmSession = htmlItem.getAttribute("data-film-session");

    if (dataFilmSession.equals(DomElement.ATTRIBUTE_NOT_DEFINED) || dataFilmSession.equals(DomElement.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_EMPTY)) {
        continue;
    }
    // your original code
}
```